# tikz-cd message pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@2-2-4 is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

The diagram

```
$\begin{tikzcd}
   & U_0 \ar[dl, "\operatorname{f}_0"]     & \ar[dr, "\operatorname{f}'_0"]                           \\
 U_1 \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}_1"]        & & V_1 \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}'_1"]                        \\
\vdots \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}_{m-1}"]  & & \vdots \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}'_{n-1}"]                 \\
U_m \ar[rr, dotted, "\operatorname{f}'"] & & V_n
\end{tikzcd}$
\end{document}
```

gets error message

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@2-2-4 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.60 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-3.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }

l.64 \end{tikzcd}
                 $
```

If I remove the rr arrow from the last row then it works.

Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz

Comment: I told you *not* to use `\operatorname` as a substitute of `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong `&` in the first row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& U_0 \ar[dl, swap, "\mathrm{f}_0"] \ar[dr, "\mathrm{f}'_0"]           \\
U_1 \ar[d, "\mathrm{f}_1"]        & & V_1 \ar[d, "\mathrm{f}'_1"]        \\
\vdots \ar[d, "\mathrm{f}_{m-1}"]  & & \vdots \ar[d, "\mathrm{f}'_{n-1}"] \\
U_m \ar[rr, dotted, "\mathrm{f}'"] & & V_n
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

I also added `swap` in the top arrow pointing left, so the label is symmetrical with the other arrow.

Don't use `\operatorname` as a substitute for `\mathrm`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have  an arrow in the first line which points to nowhere. It's solved adding a `& {}` at the place the arrow is supposed to point at.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tikzcd}
  & U_0 \ar[dl, "\operatorname{f}_0"] &{} \ar[dr, "\operatorname{f}'_0"] \\
  U_1 \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}_1"] & & V_1 \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}'_1"] & {}\\
   \vdots \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}_{m-1}"] & & \vdots \ar[d, "\operatorname{f}'_{n-1}"] \\
  U_m \ar[rr, dotted, "\operatorname{f}'"] & & V_n
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

However I'm not fully convinced your intention was to draw exactly *this*:

[image]

Comment: As noted by egreg, the problem was an extraneous ampersand

Comment: No exactly:the last arrow in the first line pointed to a direction which corresponded to no object. Not knowing what you wanted exactly, I added an `&` (and no object) to get rid of the error message.